# Neo4j - most efficient way to check if nodes with a given label exist

Tags: neo4j

I need to check if any node with the given label exists in my application. What's the most efficient approach to do so (in Java)? I was expecting
`Transaction'getAllLabelsInUse()`
to do the job, but it seems to also return `true`when any index or constraint exists for the given label.

My current workaround is running a query like this:

`` match (n:`label`) return n._id limit 1 ``

assuming it would be a bit faster than

`match (n:Crew) with n limit 1 return count(*)`

Answer (score 1):

The counts store can quickly service simple queries, such as getting the counts of all nodes of a label, so `match (n:Crew) return count(n)` will be very fast.

Take a look at our knowledge base article on [getting fast counts from the counts store](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/fast-counts-using-the-count-store/) for other alternatives that leverage the counts store.